# Classify into one of two sets (without learning)

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I am dealing with a problem where I would like to automatically divide a set into two subsets, knowing that ALMOST ALL of the objects in the set A will have greater values in all of the dimensions than objects in the set B.

I know I could use machine learning but I need it to be fully automated, as in various instances of a problem objects of set A and set B will have different values (so values in set B of the problem instance 2 might be greater than values in set A of the problem instance 1!).

[image]

I imagine the solution could be something like finding objects which are the best representatives of those two sets (the density of the objects around them is the highest).
Finding N best representatives of both sets would be sufficient for me.

Does anyone know the name of the problem and/or could propose the implementation for that? (Python is preferable).

Cheers!

Comment: K-means? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means

Comment: @DavidMarek - makes sense, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try some of the clustering methods, which belong to unsupervised machine learning. The result depends on your data and how distributed they are. According to your picture I think K-means algorithm could work. There is a python library for machine learning scikit-learn, which already contains k-means implementation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means

Answer (score 1):

If your data is as easy as you explained, then there are some rather obvious approaches.

1. Center and count:

   Center your data set, and count for each object how many values are positive. If more values are positive than negative, it will likely be in the red class.
2. Length histogram:

   Compute the sum of each vector. Make a histogram of values. Split at the largest gap, vectors longer than the threshold are in one group, the others in the lower group.

   I have made an ipython notebook to [demonstrate this approach](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/anonymous/5906e45369c593820b47) available.

[image]